# git offline check if git tag was already pushed to remote?

Tags: git

Can I ask git what it thinks which tags are on a git remote last time git checked without an online connection?

Does git keep track on to which remotes it already pushed tags?

With git branches it's possible by using `git diff --stat branch-name remote-name/branch-name`. If the branch does not exist on the remote, git diff will point that out by showing an error and non-zero exit code.

`git ls-remote origin tag` does what I want but it requires an online connection which I want to avoid.

What I would expect to work is `git diff --stat tag-name remote-name/tag-name` but seems like local tags cannot be easily compared with remote tags that way.

Purpose: With a lot of git repositories, automated, scripted, checking which tags have already been pushed, avoiding unnecessary internet connections which are slow and avoid bumping into rate limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I ask git what it thinks which tags are on a git remote last time git checked without an online connection?

Not without advanced preparation.  With the proper advanced preparation, yes.

> Does git keep track on to which remotes it already pushed tags?

No.

There's a couple of technical issues here:

- What you're actually pushing, with `git push`, are *commits*.
- But at the end of `git push`, you also ask the other Git software to create, delete, or update certain *names* in *its repository*.

Tag names are simply names ("refs") that begin with the magic sequence `refs/tags/`; the remainder of the name is the tag name.  However, tag names have special status in Git, similar to the way that branch and remote-tracking names have special statuses:

- A *branch* name (one beginning with `refs/heads/`) is constrained to point to a commit only, never to any other object.  When a branch name is transferred via `git fetch` it generally<sup>1</sup> becomes a *remote-tracking name* instead, i.e., a name beginning with `refs/remotes/` and including the name of the remote and another slash.
- A *tag name* is auto-fetched under certain conditions.
- The `git push` operation turns into a kind of operation that, on the receiving end, enforces some checking by default:

  - branch names must move in a fast-forward fashion; and
  - tag names must not move at all

  (except that in Git versions before 1.8.2, Git accidentally used the branch rules for tag names here).
- A local repository doing a `git push` to a remote repository via remote-name will, on a success status, update its remote-tracking name: that is, pushing from your laptop to GitHub, if `main` is successful, your laptop updates your `origin/main` remote-tracking names.

So we see here that branch names have all kinds of special weirdness applied, with this remote-tracking name stuff.  This keeps the *branch* names specific to any one given repository.  My branch names, in my clone of some GitHub repo, are *mine*, yours are *yours*, and we use GitHub to synchronize.

*Tag* names don't get this much weirdness (and tag names often point to tag objects rather than to commit objects), but tag names are generally considered universal substitutes for one particular commit hash ID: if I create tag `v1.2` at commit `a123456` and push to a shared repository on GitHub, GitHub accept this if and only if `v1.2` is totally new to them, and from now until forever, everyone agrees that `v1.2` is just a human-readable name for `a123456`.  Humans use `v1.2`, Git uses `a123456`, and we're all always talking about the same commit.

Since tags are only ever created, and never move, if you have tag v1.2, and I have tag v1.2, on some repository that has sharing going on, these had better refer to the exact same commit hash ID, and therefore there's no need to synchronize our `v1.2` tags.

Of course, all synchronization happens only when we can talk, on line, from my repository to your repository or to some shared third repository (e.g., on GitHub).  So it's entirely possible for me to create a `v1.2` *by accident* at the same time you're creating a `v1.2` for a *different commit*.  Git just sort of assumes that this Doesn't Happen.  If it does happen, you're pretty much on your own.

With all that understood, we can now tackle whatever your real underlying issues is by noting the following:

- `git push` and `git fetch` transfer references through *refspecs*.
- refspecs allow the creation of *maps*.  This is how remote-tracking names work.

The *default* refspec when I fetch from `origin` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This is what makes remote-tracking names appear in my repository.  If I add `--tags`, Git adds `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.  This is what causes tags *not* to have the equivalent of remote-tracking.  (The special weirdness is that without an *explicit* `--no-tags`, if I fetch commit `b789abc` and that commit is tagged `v2.2` my Git will create `refs/tags/v2.2` as well.  This special code has undergone numerous revisions in Git over many years and suffers from some degree of Git version drift, but the main effects are pretty consistent.)

The advanced preparation you can make is to *add to your default fetch refspecs* so that `git fetch origin` will force-update `refs/rtags/origin/*` or some other similar name-space based on the `refs/tags/*` names found *on* `origin`.  There won't be any magic push-like opportunistic update, but `git fetch` will pick these up.

To make this happen you just add:

```
fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/origin/*
```

to the `git config` lines for your `origin` remote; then `git fetch origin` will update your remote-tag-tracking-names.

> Purpose: With a lot of git repositories, automated, scripted, checking which tags have already been pushed ...

The above might work, but it might be simpler to keep track, using some script, of a list of remotes and/or URLs to which you've successfully run `git push <remote> <tag>` from your automated scripts.  You could store these in your `.git/config` using `git config`.  You choose the format; use something that makes your job easy for yourself.  If some remote doesn't list some tag, you can run `git push` to it, or `git ls-remote` to it, to try to push the tag and/or to check, and then update the status using `git config` to update the `.git/config` file.

(You don't have to store this in `.git/config` either, and if you're doing other Git things at the same time, you might want to use `git config --file $GIT_DIR/tag-tracking`, for instance, so that you don't run into lock contention.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that *mirror clones* have a different default refspec, such that there are no remote-tracking names.